# Imprimir un solo elemento de la lista, me sale ERROR IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, fibonacci

Quiero imprimir solo el elemento que yo le pase a la función.

```
def fib(n):
    serie = []
    a, b = 0,1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
        serie.append(a)
        print (serie[m], end='')
m = int(input("What number do you want to see: "))
fib(m)
```

Error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿quieres que imprima solo el `n-ésimo` número de la secuencia?
Si ese es el caso:

```
def fib(n):
    serie = []
    a, b = 0,1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
        serie.append(a)
    print (serie[-1])
m = int(input("What number do you want to see: "))
fib(m)
```

Y si aparte quieres que imprima toda la secuencia, solo pones

```
print (serie, serie[-1])
```